# Dynamic URLs Without Creating a .html for each user

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, dynamic

I'm working on creating a website similar to oc.tc. The website system, not the content. Anyway, if you notice how you can do oc.tc/itunes89(Or oc.tc/anyregistereduser) I would like to know how to do that. I don't think there creating pages for everyone, I think there dynamically doing this.

*I've already created a system, like username=user and id=12. I would like to know how to do that without triggering a 404 error.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: This happens on the server side. Which web server are you using? For Apache, use [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html).

Comment: It would also help to know what server-side technology you're using...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using Apache?

If so, welcome to the amazing world of Apache's mod_rewrite. (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

Here's the basic concept: you define rules that "rewrite" a URL like `oc.tc/itunes89` into `oc.tc/show_user.php?username=itunes89` (or whatever you want).

This is an excellent guide to mod_rewrite: http://www.sitepoint.com/guide-url-rewriting-2/. Let me know if you have a specific question or problem implementing it.

Answer (score 1):

For Apache Tomcat, you can do such things if you map a servlet to a certain URL pattern, and then show the correct page. A tutorial that shows an example can be found [here](http://keyboardsamurais.de/2003/11/29/tomcat_tutorial_helloworld_for_complete_fools_/). Together with the source code of the JSPServlet ( [here](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/tomcat/trunk/java/org/apache/jasper/servlet/JspServlet.java) ), you can put together your own servlet that does what you want. I think the method used to retrieve the path is HttpRequest.getServletPath() and HttpRequest.getPathInfo(), but you best just try to understand the source code i pointed to (the service(..) method is the one that is called when you access the servlet).